# Notebook screen bezel pop open,no screws

Tags: laptop, hp-pavilion, laptop-repair

I was trying to open my hp-r062tu notebook pc but suddenly a crack sound is heard ,my screen bezel popped off on one corner, my screen has no screws for bezel, i tried to make it stick by applying pressure but its not sticking i am afraid to close the lid as it may enlarge the pop.Is there any way to make it stick.

The issue in applying glue is if at anytime i need to replace it ,bezel would not come off easily and the screen may also get damaged.How was the bezel attached to the screen till now, with any adhesive if it is can you name it.

[damaged bezel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JH2pT.jpg)

Comment: A model number or a photo of the damage might be a good place to start getting some recommendations from folks here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Bezel is clipped, The crack means that most likely the clip is now Brocken.
I can suggest:

- you decide to change only the Bezel: Finding a provider for it will be quite a task and then dismantling a screen is also no easy feat, and have good chance to add new damage. With some courage, you should be able to make it.
- (best quality price - home made repair) Use anything to clip it back (Tape is an option) **BUT** do it on the **outside** and not on the inside: all glues contains aggressive agents and have a good chance to damage your screen
- You go to a repair specialist
- buy a new computer